# Angular2 input type last value cached

Tags: angular, typescript2.0

I have a dropdown with 2 values "Used, New"  and depending on which one you select the relevant text input miles/km conversion boxes are displayed.

Entering miles converts to km and vice versa - this works fine.

Steps leading to problem:-

1) **Used** is selected by default - enter miles and km is converted - works

2) Select **New** from DD and enter a miles value and km is converted - works

3) Select **Used** and all values in textboxes cleared - works

4) Select **New** from DD and the **km** textbox still has the last converted value but the **miles** textbox is empty ... PROBLEM

In a nutshell the last value converted to - persists in the session -

Thanks in advance...

HTML

```
<select class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="SelectedCarType" >
<option *ngFor="let c of CarTypes" [value]="c.CarTypeId">
   {{c.CarDescription}}</option>
</select>

<div *ngIf="SelectedCarType === 1" class="form-group" style="width:50%">
<label class="label label-info" for="Mileage">Mileage:</label>
<input class="form-control" type="number" name="Mileage" id="Mileage" 
(input)="convertToKm($event.target.value,$event.target.id)" value="{{miles}} 
"  />
</div>

<div *ngIf="SelectedCarType ==1" class="form-group" style="width:50%">
<label class="label label-info" for="Kilometres">Kilometres:</label>
<input class="form-control" type="number" name="Kilometres" 
id="Kilometres"  
(input)="convertToMiles($event.target.value,$event.target.id)" value="{{km}}"  />
</div>

<div >
  <div *ngIf="SelectedCarType ==2" class="form-group" style="width:50%">
    <label class="label label-info" for="Mileage">Mileage:</label>
     <input class="form-control" type="number" name="Mileage" 
   id="Mileage" (input)="convertToKm($event.target.value,$event.target.id)" 
   value="{{milesUsed}} "  />
  </div>

    <div *ngIf="SelectedCarType ==2" class="form-group" style="width:50%">
        <label class="label label-info" for="Kilometres">Kilometres:</label>
        <input class="form-control" type="number" name="Kilometres" 
        id="Kilometres" 
        (input)="convertToMiles($event.target.value,$event.target.id)" 
        value="{{kmUsed}}"  />
    </div>
```

Typescript File

```
export class Vehicle implements OnInit {
public selectedCarClaimType: number;
public CarClaimTypes: WarrantyClaimType[];
public km: number;
public miles: number;
public kmUsed: number;
public milesUsed: number;     

 convertToMiles(kmValue: string, id: string) {
    let result: number = Number(kmValue);
    this.miles = null;
    this.milesUsed = null;

    switch (id) {
    case 'Kilometres':
            this.miles = result / 1.6;
            this.milesUsed = null;
            this.kmUsed = null;
        break;
    case 'KilometresTravelled':
            this.milesUsed = result / 1.6;
            this.miles = null;
            this.km = null;
        break;
    }
}

convertToKm(milesValue: string, id: string) {
    let result: number = Number(milesValue);
    this.km = null;
    this.kmUsed = null;
    switch (id) {
    case 'Mileage':
            this.km = result * 1.6;
            this.kmUsed = null;
            this.milesUsed = null;

        break;
    case 'MileageTravelled':
            this.kmUsed = result * 1.6;
            this.miles = null;
            this.km = null;

        break;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Removed the ConvertToKm and ConvertToMiles with below and checked the value being passed and control name:-

```
 convert(searchValue: string, id: string)
 {
    if (searchValue === '')
    {
        if (id === 'Kilometres' || id === 'Mileage')
        {
        this.miles = null;
        this.km = null;
        }
        else
        {
         this.milesUsed = null;
        this.kmUsed = null;
        }
        return;
    }

    let result: number = Number(searchValue);

    switch (id) {
        case 'Kilometres':
            this.miles = result / 1.6;
            this.km = result;
        break;
        case 'KilometresTravelled':
            this.milesUsed = result / 1.6;
            this.kmUsed = result;
        break;
    case 'Mileage':
        this.km = result * 1.6;
        this.miles = result;
        break;
    case 'MileageTravelled':
        this.kmUsed = result * 1.6;
        this.milesUsed = result;
        break;

    }


  }
```